# Unable to add Facebook Android SDK project to the Library field

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, project

I believe I've looked everywhere possible and already feel to silly because I spent literally hours on this without any success.

I follow the instructions for creating the two initial projects (Facebook Android SDK and the Test project):
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#ref

But when it comes to selecting the project by clicking on the "Add..." button, it does not really show anything in the list and my test project is full of errors because the Facebook Android SDK library has not been referenced.

Could you help me out on this one, please?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the FB Android SDK project is marked as "Is Library"? Right click that project, Properties -> Android -> Check "Is Library"

Comment: Thanks very much! I hadn't marked the SDK project as a library, but now having done so, it does work properly. It was really silly of myself, but once again I'd like to say a big thanks to both yourself and Nick.

Answer (score 0):

In your Facebook Android SDK-Project, make sure you checked the "Is Library"-Checkbox in the "Properties" --> "Android" dialog

Comment: Thanks very much! I hadn't checked the box before, because I did not see such indication anywhere before (but I guess I just missed it).

Answer (score 0):

Actually Just totally copy the facebook SDK into your project. It will work that way only.